# Fix step bindings in SpecFlow

Tags: specflow

My SpecFlow step match definitions suddenly stopped working and won't return.
The specs and steps are located in different assemblies and are bound using the correspondent line inside the App.config file.
This feature used to work: able to navigate to the step definition, colouring etc.

Also cleaned the cache and restarted the VS number of times.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what changed? new extension version? updated nuget package? did you change the name of the assembly the steps are in? When you say cleaned the cache you mean deleted the files in %temp%? Was visual studio shut at the time?

Comment: 1) Nothing changed - for instance, the step matches vanished after a check-in
2) No
3) No
4) No
5) Yes
6) Yes